# Countability in the Integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis in chapter 2, it says that the integers are countable as a set because of having the same cardinality as the positive integers. However it's just not making sense because, as the paper counts out the integers $0, 1, -1, 2, -2...$ I think of adding in $\infty$ and - $\infty$. In the positive integers to match that I add in $\infty$ plus an ordinal number higher than that one; that induces another step of adding another ordinal to the integers and the positive integers end up with 1 more cardinality. What is the mistake?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question, but $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not integers (nor do ordinal numbers come into play, really) - hence why Rudin would not consider them.

Comment: same cardinality means they can be put in one-to-one correspondence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of integers is numerable because you can put it into a one to one correspondence. For instance you can

1. $0\to 0$
2. $1\to +1$
3. $2 \to-1$
4. $3 \to +2$
5. $4 \to -2$

and so on.

Comment: -- thanks people

Comment: I have just tried reading it again and I lost track, because there isn't infinity this time. If there are twice as many integers than positive integers, how is there a 1 : 1 correspondence when the terms seemingly run out?

Comment: @LolFlo Where do they run out? The 1-1 correspondence in this answer shows that there aren’t twice as many.

Comment: For example, how is counting possible after counting the positive numbers first?

Comment: I'll rephrase - picture the negative integers have cardinality equal to the positive integers. The positive integers also have that cardinality. It doesn't add up for me!

Comment: it approaches different infinities or the same infinity in either direction so im a lil confused today - _-.

Comment: Yes, the integers, the positive integers and the negative integers all have the same cardinality. This _does_ "add up"; it simply says $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.